# Icon for a Loadable Bundle

Tags: macos, icons, bundle

I have a loadable bundle; not an application.  I store the icns file in the Resource directory and the Info.plist has the correct entry for CFBundleIconFile.  How do I know?  I have used the same technique and a differnt icon on a test application. I have even rebuilt the "lsregister".  Neither 10.6.x or 10.7.x show the icon in the Finder.

I have changed the icon in the Finder using the copy/paste into the Get Info icon.  This produces a hidden file with a resource fork called Icon^M.

Questions:
1) Is there a way to get the icon to appear in a loadable bundle?
2) Is there a shell program or way to change the Get Info icon programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in the -iconForFile method of the NSWorkspace Class. I built a Command Line Tool the takes the image I need and uses the above method to set the icon.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:content forFile:targetFile options: NSExclude10_4ElementsIconCreationOption ];
```

where content is the NSImage content of the icon and targetFile is the path to the target bundle.